# Could Zapata’s Flying airboard be used on Space missions

Tags: propulsion

The following Zapata’s flying air board (FAB) can fly on Earth for 10 minutes up to 3km ceiling, carrying 100kg person at a speed of 150km/hr. I was wondering if it could fly on Moon or Mars, or around ISS or does it need air like jet plain? I am not entirely understand the propulsion system.

https://robbreport.com/motors/aviation/jet-powered-hoverboard-flyboard-air-radical-design-1234794530/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyboard_Air

The kerosin will be available, and the board itself is light and compact for space transportation. Many EVA uses could be done in growing space industry like lava tube/canyon(Mars) where spacesuit weight is offset by lower gravity.

Do you think it’s feasible to modify it to feed air from astronaut spacesuit’s backpack? For example on Mars CO2 could by converted to oxygen to replenish supplies.

Comment: Would [engineering.se] be a better hoem for this question?

Answer (score 3):

> Would Zapata’s Flying airboard work without air?

No. It is a turbojet pack, not a rocket pack - it is powered by jet turbines so it needs air, just like a jet aeroplane.